# Ways to XML serialize multiple objects in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

What are different ways in which we can XML serialize multiple objects of same/different types?

For example, Generic `List<T>` for same type of objects
and ArrayList for different type of objects.

Also, which type of structures are XML serializable and which are not?

It would be helpful if anyone can provide with sample piece of code or a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be serializable via `XmlSerializer`, your types must

- be public
- have a public parameterless constructor
- it serializes the public read/write fields and properties (properties being preferred)

In terms of which constructs;

- individual concrete entities are fine
- concrete lists/arrays (`List<T>`, `T[]`, etc) are handled fine
- but it will struggle with interfaces, dictionaries, and various generics scenarios (other than lists)

You are right that `List<T>` is fine for serializing a set of like objects. If you are dealing with subclasses, then `[XmlInclude]` can be used to distinguish types; i.e. if you have:

```
var list = new List<ParentType>();
list.Add(new ParentType());
list.Add(new ChildType()); // Child : Parent
```

then this may still be serializable as long as you have:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Child))]
public class Parent {}

public class Child : Parent {}
```

(you can also specify this relationship in the ctor to `XmlSerializer`, but it is extra work)

I don't recommend using `IXmlSerializable` unless you have to; it is complex and hard to get right. More importantly; it doesn't work **at all* if you are using wsdl-generated proxy objects over a SOAP service; the other end won't have your `IXmlSerializable` implementation.

I also don't recommend serializing lists of arbitrary object types; if you have a *finite set* of known types there are tricks to do this utilising `[XmlInclude]` etc.

Comment: The parameterless constructor does not have to be public.

Answer (score 1):

You could make all your classes implement System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable. You could then have a generic collection of this type. It is then very simple to implement the ReadXml and WriteXml methods required.

e.g.

```
class MyClass : IXmlSerializable
{
        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {            
        }

        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            //TODO: read logic here...
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            //TODO: write logic here...
        }
}
```

Usage...

```
class WorkerClass
{
  public void SerializeListToFile(IList<IXmlSerializable> list, string fileName)
  {
    using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileName))
    {
      foreach (IXmlSerializable item in list)
        item.WriteXml(writer);

      writer.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for [Xml serialization of collections](http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=542). But Chris Arnold is right implementing `IXmlSerializable` will allow you to have full control on the serialization. Xml attributes are attractive because they are declarative but the other option is worth learning (and is faster from my experience).